# Php code gets a blank page

Tags: php, debugging, authentication

this code is giving back a **blank page** in browser. Can you spot any mistake? permissions and url checked. The phpcodechecker.com says it's allright

```
<?php
    # Check for POST login data, else set initial values
    if (isset($_POST["user"])) {
        $user=$_POST['user'];
        $pass=hash('sha256',$_POST['pass']);
    }
    else {
        $user="";
        $pass="";
    }

    # Check Login Data
    #
    # Password is hashed (SHA256). In this case it is 'admin'.
    if($user == "admin"
    && $pass == "8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918")
    {
        # Load content from local storage
        include("../localstorage/content.html");
    }
    else
    {
        # Show login form. Request for username and password
echo
            '<html>
            <body>      
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br/>
                    Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br/>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>'

    }
?>
```

*(I downloaded it from http://www.canbike.org/information-technology/2014/02/05/php-simple-password-protection-with-session-timeout.html and i'm concious of its lack of safety)*

Comment: Check your error logs; this is a parser error. As the answer below says, the problem is the invalid use of `<?`.

Comment: Hi @EdCottrell, thanks but that didn't fix my problem, keeps white :(

Comment: You're also missing a `;` after the final `'`.

Comment: I feel stupid, that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortcut open tag used but not allowed on third line up from bottom?

```
<?
```

Answer (score 6):

use echo statement to print the html code as follows.

```
echo '<html>
            <body>      
                <form method="POST" action="">
                    Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br/>
                    Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br/>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>';
```

and remove the in between php tags, use only outer php tags at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 1):

I am late for this question but anyway i want to answer this question.
First of all, if you are new in PHP then You should change error_reporting line in your php.ini as follows:

```
error_reporting=E_ALL
```

because this setting display **Parse Error** instead of **Black Page** if there is any parse error.

---

Solution of your question:
There is a **Syntax Error** in last 'echo' statement of your script which is generating **Parse Error**.
You can remove this syntax error by adding semicolon(;) in last echo statement as follow:

```
else{
echo

        '<html>
        <body>      
            <form method="POST" action="">
                Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br/>
                Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use docstring to write html in php files.

```
<<<EOD
<html>
        <body>      
            <form method="POST" action="">
                Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br/>
                Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </body>
</html> 
EOD;
```